# MongoDb/ Mongoose Aggregation Issue With Matching Date

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose, aggregate, iso

I am trying to use Mongoose/ MongoDb's aggregate function to match documents based on the date. While my aggregate function matches documents by other filters, It is simply not working based on date. I am sharing my code below.

```
"$match": {
    "createdAt": {"$lt": new Date()}
}
```

I was trying a variety of different dates, Starting with the ISO date stored in my mongoDb database, But none of them seem to work. I have no idea what is the reason for this issue. While I had searched online extensively, I did not find anything conclusive. The same query executed over the mongoDb shell works fine, Leading me to believe that this may be an issue with Mongoose and the way it casts the Date.

This is the data I was testing with

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("5be7fc909625592852d422b4"),
     "time" : ISODate("2018-11-11T09:55:28.704Z"),
    "receiver" : ObjectId("5be5d727d3f24e06b144e229"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-11-11T09:55:28.718Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-11-11T09:55:28.718Z"),
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5be807902b789e5c3c05dc5e"),
    "time" : ISODate("2018-11-11T10:42:24.410Z"),
    "receiver" : ObjectId("5be5d727d3f24e06b144e229"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-10-09T18:30:00Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-10-09T18:30:00Z"),
}
```

I am stuck, With no idea how to proceed ahead. I have tried everything from my understanding but nothing seems to work. I hope I can get some help on this issue.

Much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: please provide your data sample

Comment: Please check the edit

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please calrify "does not seem to work". Are you getting an error? Too many documents? or none?

Comment: My bad. What I meant 'does not seem to work' was that the aggregate function returned no documents ie matched no documents when I ran the query against the date.

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly facing a timezone problem. I just tried the call of `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` inside `node` and inside `mongo`. Both return different results (node returns `-60`, mongo shell returns `0` on my machine).

You can remove the timezone offset with the following code:

```
let d = new Date()
var offset = d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000 // This converts the given minutes to milliseconds.
var utc = d.getTime() + offset
var nd = new Date(utc)

"$match": {
    "createdAt": { "$lt": nd }
}
```

When you convert the time you should now get the expected results.

This is sensible as MongoDB uses UTC as time format. The conversion might seem a bit cumbersome in vanilla JavaScript. You could alternatively use a library like `moment.js`.

Comment: I was trying this yesterday, But I was still unable to match the documents using the code you shared. I did get an idea from what you said - And tested my code on the node terminal using my mongoose models. Surprisingly I was able to match the condition here, Using the exact same query I shared. I suspect this is something wrong from my side, Maybe I am casting the date wrong ?  I'll have to keep trying - But thanks for your help @mbuechmann

Comment: @DaminHan you can always call `toString()` on any date value. Perhaps in this way you can find the relevant discrepancies.